# iptables forward traffic between three interfaces

Tags: iptables, openvpn, openconnect

I'm trying to understand what is doing wrong (i'm newbie on iptables) with my iptables configuration.

I'm having 3 interfaces running in the same machine and the connections was established in this secuence:

Server:

tun0: OpenVPN Server established.

tun1: Openconnect established.

ppp0: Openfortivpn established.

Client:

```
OpenVPN established to Openvpn on server (tun0).
```

I want to:

1. All packages on my client to destiny 10.176.86.54 goes from tun0 to tun1.
2. All my packages to destiny 100.126.20.133 goes from tun0 to ppp0.

So i did this configuration:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o ppp0 -d 100.126.20.133 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o tun0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o tun1 -d 10.176.86.54 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun1 -o tun0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

After all VPNs stablished this is my netstat -rn

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 tun1
10.0.0.0        10.111.242.83   255.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 ppp0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
10.206.145.0    10.111.242.83   255.255.255.128 UG        0 0          0 ppp0
13.80.125.22    192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
13.91.91.243    192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
40.81.156.154   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
40.90.218.198   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
52.174.56.180   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
52.183.75.62    192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
52.184.165.82   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
52.238.78.88    192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
52.238.119.141  192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
52.244.160.207  192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
100.70.132.228  10.111.242.83   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 ppp0
100.70.133.194  10.111.242.83   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 ppp0
100.123.0.0     10.111.242.83   255.255.0.0     UG        0 0          0 ppp0
100.125.16.0    10.111.242.83   255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 ppp0
100.126.0.0     10.111.242.83   255.255.0.0     UG        0 0          0 ppp0
100.127.4.0     10.111.242.83   255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 ppp0
104.42.230.91   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
128.10.0.0      10.111.242.83   255.255.0.0     UG        0 0          0 ppp0
128.14.1.0      10.111.242.83   255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 ppp0
131.253.33.215  192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
132.147.0.0     10.111.242.83   255.255.0.0     UG        0 0          0 ppp0
135.244.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U         0 0          0 tun1
135.245.52.100  192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
172.16.0.0      10.111.242.83   255.240.0.0     UG        0 0          0 ppp0
190.144.144.252 10.111.242.83   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 ppp0
190.144.240.101 192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
192.0.2.1       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
192.168.0.0     10.111.242.83   255.255.0.0     UG        0 0          0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
200.118.0.0     10.111.242.83   255.255.255.128 UG        0 0          0 ppp0
204.79.197.215  192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
```

On my openvpn server conf i pushed the routes to my client:

```
push "route 10.176.86.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 100.126.0.0 255.255.0.0"
```

But if is not working, thanks for your support.

Comment: The tool's name is `iptables`, not `iptable`. You should explain in detail for one example packet what it does now (source and destination address, routing) and what you want it to do instead. Shall the destination address be changed or the routing?

Comment: "Shall the destination address be changed or the routing? –  Hauke Laging"

Hi @HaukeLaging, maybe this is my problem, start VPNs over VPNs are making a trouble for my aim, i will check my ip route configuration, thanks.